# Please make sure you have specified a valid MySQL database name in 'include/config.php'

Tags: php, mysql, psql, cacti

I've just downloaded `cacti` and I kept getting

> FATAL: Cannot connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'. Please make sure you have specified a valid MySQL database name in 'include/config.php'

---

This is what I have in `include/config.php`

```
$database_type = "mysql";
$database_default = "cacti";
$database_hostname = "localhost";
$database_username = "root";
$database_password = "***";
$database_port = "3306";
$database_ssl = false;
```

---

What did I forget or did wrong ?

Comment: "cannot connect"... did you check if mysql is actually running?

Comment: I can connect to my localhost dbs fine via MySQL Workbench.

Comment: can you show the code that actually connects, can you confirm that that database exists ?

Comment: @ihue, using the exact same settings shown above? Are you running any VMs, Docker containers, etc?

Comment: I download [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and place it in my `public/`directory of my local Mac on MAMP. Then I go to, `http://localhost:8888/cacti/` then I see that error.

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you try connecting to '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'?

Comment: @Martin : I've tried `mysql -u root -p'***'` and I can connect fine.

Comment: Ok, Can you show the code that generates the MySQL connection instruction (`PDO::__construct` or something similar)  ?

Comment: @Martin : I don't write this cacti stuff, but I'll update my post with the info you requested.

Comment: @Martin : I looked almost eveyfile in cacti folder, I couldn't anything with that `PDO::_construct`. I'll dig more.

Comment: I have no experience of `cacti` but just wanted to double check that the connection php function was being handled the proper way.